# Vuetify custom validation for confirm password

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working on Vue.js template and on the sign up page, I need to compare password while user signup so, I added custom validation rule like the following code:

```
<v-text-field 
    label="Password" 
    v-model="password" 
    :rules="passwordRules" 
    type="password" 
    required
></v-text-field>
<v-text-field 
    label="Confirm Password" 
    v-model="confirmPassword" 
    :rules="[confirmPasswordRules,passwordConfirmationRule]"
    type="password" 
    required
></v-text-field>
```

script:

```
data() {
    return {
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
        passwordRules: [v => !!v || "Password is required"],
        confirmPasswordRules: [v => !!v || "Password is required"],
    };
},
```

Compare password method in computed:

```
computed: {
    passwordConfirmationRule() {
        return () => (this.password === this.confirmPassword) || 'Password must match'
    },
}
```

I use the computed method for confirm password its working fine and compare the password perfectly but it shows error in console `[Vuetify] Rules should return a string or boolean, received 'object' instead`  so how can I solve this ??

Answer (score 11):

You're getting the error message because the `rules` property of the "Confirm Password" input doesn't contain a one-dimensional array containing the rules, but instead contains `confirmPasswordRules` which is an array itself plus the `passwordConfirmationRule` rule.

So essentially this

```
:rules="[confirmPasswordRules, passwordConfirmationRule]"
```

contains this:

```
:rules="[[v => !!v || "Password is required"], (this.password === this.confirmPassword) || 'Password must match']"
```

You want all of the rules to be contained in a single array instead. You can use the `concat` method to add the `passwordConfirmationRule` to the `confirmPasswordRules` array like this:

```
:rules="confirmPasswordRules.concat(passwordConfirmationRule)"
```

I've created a Codepen to show that this works [here](https://codepen.io/asdasgqq/pen/ZEYezrd).

Answer (score 10):

you can use

template :

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="password"
  label="Password"
  name="password"
  prepend-icon="mdi-lock"
  type="password"
  :rules="passwordRules"
/>

<v-text-field
  v-model="confirmPassword"
  label="Confirm Password"
  name="confirmPassword"
  prepend-icon="mdi-lock"
  type="password"
  :rules="confirmPasswordRules"
/>
```

script:

```
data() {
    return {
      password: '',
      confirmPassword: '',
      passwordRules: [
        (value) => !!value || 'Please type password.',
        (value) => (value && value.length >= 6) || 'minimum 6 characters',
      ],
      confirmPasswordRules: [
        (value) => !!value || 'type confirm password',
        (value) =>
          value === this.password || 'The password confirmation does not match.',
      ],
    }
},
```

Comment: `this.password` is always empty in the `confirmPasswordRules`. Do you guys know why?

Comment: Interesting, if i put that rule in the tag itself, it worked. 
Ex:
`:rules="[!!confirmPassword || 'type confirm password', password === confirmPassword || 'The password confirmation does not match.']"`

Comment: It does not work when the first password is changed, the rules of the second field are not triggered.

Comment: I think I will clear the second field whenever the first field is changed. Or, I can trigger the form validation after the first changes.

Answer (score 3):

template

```
<v-text-field
  label="Password"
  v-model="password"
  :rules="[rules.passwordRules]"
  type="password"
  required>
</v-text-field>
<v-text-field
  label="Confirm Password"
  v-model="confirmPassword"
  :rules="[rules.confirmPasswordRules, passwordConfirmationRule]"
  @update:error="checkPassword"
  type="password"
  required>
</v-text-field>
```

script

```
data() {
  return {
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
    validPassword: "",
    rules: {
      passwordRules: v => !!v || "Password is required",
      confirmPasswordRules: v => !!v || "Password is required"
    }
  };
},
methods: {
  checkPassword(invalid) { 
    // correct: false
    if (true == invalid) {
      this.validPassword = false;
    } else {
      this.validPassword = true;
    }
   },
 }
```

> text-field provides an "update:error" event. If the password is valid, it executes a function of that event and returns false. 
>   Returns true to a function when it is changed from a valid password to an invalid password.

Comment: So how can I achieve what I want ?? if Rules should return a string or boolean, received 'function' instead. As per your answer, I just validate with the required field but I need to confirm password as well as required field.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake. I mistook the computed attribute for methods. I updated my article.

Comment: I don`t want to check valid or invalid passwords I just want to compare both passwords to make signup but your code is not compared passwords anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to solve the problem that I think is worth for anyone coming for a solution.

In my template I have the following:

```
<v-text-field
   v-model.trim="passwordRepeat"
   label="Confirm Password"
   type="password"
   autocomplete="new-password"
   prepend-icon="mdi-lock-check"
   required
   :rules="repeatPasswordRules"
/>
```

And in my script section:

```
computed: {
  repeatPasswordRules() {
    return [
      (v) => !!v || 'Senha não informada',
      (v) => (v && v.length >= 8) || 'A senha deve ter no mínimo 8 caracteres',
      (v) => (v === this.password) || 'Senhas diferentes!',
    ];
  },
},
```

And of course, don't forget the validation call

```
validate() {
  const valid = this.$refs.signup.validate();
  if(valid) {      
    //your actions after validation
  }
}
```